# Airflow upgrade_check returning command error

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am migrating airflow from 1.10.15 to 2.4.3 and I am trying to run `airflow upgrade_check` command to check and get recommendation about the actual state of airflow install.

I am running airflow 2.4.3 in a docker container using docker-compose and python 3.9

I have the following error:

> airflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: invalid choice: 'upgrade_check' (choose from 'celery', 'cheat-sheet', 'config', 'connections', 'dag-processor', 'dags', 'db', 'info', 'jobs', 'kerberos', 'kubernetes', 'plugins', 'pools', 'providers', 'roles', 'rotate-fernet-key', 'scheduler', 'standalone', 'sync-perm', 'tasks', 'triggerer', 'users', 'variables', 'version', 'webserver'), see help above.

I have tried adding `airflow upgrade_check` in Dockerfile but without success. I have also tried to run `pip install apache-airflow-upgrade-check` in the container, and it was showing that all requirements are already satisfied: `Requirement already satisfied`

Did anyone get the same issue ? Any recommendations ?

Comment: How did you run the 1st version? Using docker?

Comment: yes using Docker

Comment: yes. but you wrote that inside docker `airflow 2.4.3`. what do you want to update?

Comment: I was running both 1.10.15 and 2.4.3 inside a docker container. I have modified my docker-compose by upgrading airflow version